# C# Difference of two time Values one is xml other one is current time

Tags: c#, time

I have two time values one is stored in xml file

```
<bicycle>
    <Id>3002</Id>
    <TimeSpan>5/23/2020 7:11:02 AM</TimeSpan>
    <CurrentLocation>0</CurrentLocation>
    <UserId>1521217035</UserId>
  </bicycle>
```

Calling this value from code

```
 node.SelectSingleNode("TimeSpan").InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

other time value is system current time How can i compare these two and get difference?

Comment: DateTime.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("TimeSpan").InnerText).Subtract(DateTime.Now.ToString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeSpan span = date2 - date1;
double seconds = span.TotalSeconds;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1

For more info.

Also date2 and date1 are DateTime types. Convert your string using Convert.ToDateTime or DateTime.ParseExact